# How to get value of specific element using XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this xml code:

```
    <DataObjects>
    <DataOb Code="Object.First">
        <Ro Code="Row10">
            <Co Code="Column10">145875</Co>
            <Co Code="Column20">23456</Co>
        </Ro>
        <Ro Code="Row20">
            <Co Code="Column10">2486</Co>
            <Co Code="Column20">1348646</Co>
        </Ro>
    </DataOb>
</DataObjects>
```

I'm using XSL to transform my xml file and I don't know how to get for example only value 2486. How I can specified that the value is in element `<Co Code="Column10">` that is child of element `<Ro Code="Row20">`.

Thank you
George

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most precise XPath-1.0 expression to retrieve the value "2486" is

```
/DataObjects/DataOb[@Code='Object.First']/Ro[@Code='Row20']/Co[@Code='Column10']
```

In XSLT-1.0, this would be

```
<xsl:value-of select="/DataObjects/DataOb[@Code='Object.First']/Ro[@Code='Row20']/Co[@Code='Column10']" />
```

---

> How I can specified that the value is in element `<Co Code="Column10">` that is child of element `<Ro Code="Row20">`.

To retrieve the value exactly like you want, you should use the XPath-1.0 expression

```
//Co[@Code='Column10'][parent::Ro[@Code='Row20']]
```

or, simplified

```
//Ro[@Code='Row20']/Co[@Code='Column10']
```